# Behavior of something caused by a known exterior cause/phenomenon

Tags: phrase-choice

I would like to know the proper form to refer to the reaction of an object X to an exterior cause Y. Is it correct to say

> X's behavior towards Y

Or maybe

> X's behavior against Y

Is more appropriate ?

Comment: Effects are not usually said to behave towards or against their causes. When the apple falls, it is not behaving towards gravity. Please supply a complete sentence giving additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard phrasing for what you are looking for is

> The effect of **Y** on **X**

that Y causes X to somehow change.

You could also use if appropriate

> the reaction of X to Y
>   X is effected by Y
>   the changes in X caused by Y